# "Are you sure..." pop-up when saving file in Word

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2016

How can I add pop-up "Are you sure you want to save this file?" when I press ctrl+s in Word 2016, with VBA.

I was able to do it in Excel 2016 by adding `Application.OnKey "^s", "Macro_Name"` command to  "ThisWorkbook" in "personal.xlsb". So when I press ctrl+s it runs the macro. How can I achieve this in Word 2016?

Comment: In Excel you would do this *correctly* by handling the `BeforeClose` event in `ThisWorkbook`, not by hijacking the Ctrl+S shortcut key (your macro won't run if the Save command wasn't triggered by the hotkey then)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon that is the point. I want to stop accidental saves with ctrl+s.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a VBA macro. Without testing, here is what I think it may look like:

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, _
  SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Result As Long
    Result = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save?", vbYesNo)
    If Result = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This code leverages the
[Application.DocumentBeforeSave event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentbeforesave),
that occurs before any open document is saved.

For more information about VBA macros, see the Microsoft article
[Create or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c).

Comment: Yes, but how to bind it to ctrl+s?

Comment: Ctrl-S will call this macro before it executes, so you first get a dialog with the message "Are you sure you want to save?" and with two options for Yes and No. Pressing No will abort, pressing Yes will do the Save.

Comment: OK. Where do I save this snippet?

Comment: Inside the document. See the above Microsoft link on macros, but many other sources exist if more detail is required.

Comment: Yes sir, but I would like to be accessible in every word document and when I open blank new document.

Comment: Adding the macro to the global document template, `Normal.dotm`, makes it available to all documents. The location for `Normal.dotm` is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`, but only Word can create it if not already there.

Comment: I have added the snippet to Normal.dotm, but nothing happens what I press ctrl+s.

Comment: Is your document of type `.docm`? Macros are not allowed in `.docx` for security reasons.

Comment: @ harrymc 49 Yes.

Comment: I can already see an error of a copy-paste parasitic character in the sub name : should be `App_DocumentBeforeSave` and not `oApp_DocumentBeforeSave`. I will be trying it out this weekend.

Comment: This might be more complicated than I thought. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054965/word-vba-documentbeforesave-event).